# Shapefile rings not finite and not being read by R - how to fix?

Tags: r, arcgis, shapefile

I am trying to have R read a shapefile of a simple landscape classification (posted [here](http://temp-share.com/show/3YgF8Kd4x)) and am getting an error

```
shape1 <-readShapePoly("JustForest_BahiaSul_1990_Test.shp", force_ring=TRUE, delete_null_obj=TRUE)
Error in Polygon(coords = crds) : ring not closed
```

The same error results when I try with rgdal as an alternative:

```
shape1 <-readOGR("JustForest_BahiaSul_1990_Test.shp", layer="JustForest_BahiaSul_1990_Test")OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile
Source: "JustForest_BahiaSul_1990_Test.shp", layer: "JustForest_BahiaSul_1990_Test"
with 19122 features and 6 fields Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensionsError in stopifnot(is.list(srl)) : ring not closed
```

It was pointed out by a very helpful R colleague that the reason R is not reading the shapefile properly is because the shapefile has infinite (NaN) coordinates in entity 15755.

Now that I know the problem, I'm a bit closer to the solution.  However, I have no idea how to go about making the coordinates finite.  Thanks in advance.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Usually with the parameter ´force_ring=TRUE´ the error doesn´t appear any more. Try only with that parameter, it worked for me.

Greetings!